# Date Formatting in iPhone SDk

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm working on one iPhone application that includes date formatting. Here i'm getting date string from the server that i need to change and display of the formatted date.

Please find the below date m getting from the server

Server Date: Sat Apr 23 16:35:33 +0000 2011

This date i need to display like 2:35 AM Apr 23rd

Can anyone please help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `NSDateFormatter` to parse the date string you get from the server and get the corresponding `NSDate` (via `-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]`). You would then use a second `NSDateFormatter` to convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString` with the desired date format. Unless you absolutely require a very specific display format, you should use `+[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:]` to get a date format that a) includes all the details you want it to include and b) respects the user’s locale settings. For instance, some users might prefer a 24-hour format instead of the 12-hour format with an AM/PM designation.